# How to calculate Network bandwidth, disk space, processing power and memory of a msg

Tags: networking

I need to calculate the Network bandwidth, disk space, processing power and memory of some messages that i exchanged between two computers (sender and receiver).

For example if the message is "I am working for three (3) hours"
How much network bandwidth will it use?
How much disk space will be used?
How much processing power will be utilize at the sender and the receiving end?
How much disk space will be used at both the ends?

if i will send this message 10, 100, or 1000 times.

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you plan to send, process, and store the message.

ASCII is one byte per character, or 7 bits if you're restricting it to printable characters.   So "I am working for three (3) hours" is 32 bytes.  If you wrote that to a file 1000 times, you'd have 32000 bytes.  If you compressed it, it would be much smaller; text compresses well.

Sending it over the network would depend on the protocol you're using to send it; plan on a few hundred bytes of overhead for each message.  You can use Wireshark or iptraf to get a detailed view of how much network traffic is passing through your machine.

The processing power required to send or receive 32000 bytes is negligible.  In general, your computer's network bandwidth will become a bottleneck before you the CPU, unless you're doing something complex with the input/output.